# how to use TortoiseSVN in a network?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN for my project. I have installed in my system and added the project in the SVN repository and made a develop copy.

How to access the codes from other system and compare the codes with the server system.

Answer (score 3):

- Go on a [Test Drive](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html).
- Read [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html).